# how to calculate rolling mean for all values of a column of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, mean, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe with columns A,B and C. C has values 1, 2, 3, 4. I want to create another column D with values such that- NaN, 1.5 (=(1+2)/2), 2 (=(1+2+3)/3, 2.5(=(1+2+3+4)/4). Basically rolling mean from 1st element to ith element for which rolling mean has to be calculated. 
Help is appreciated.

I am using python and tried `rolling.mean()` but windows parameter -unable to use.

Comment: "but windows parameter -unable to use" - how exactly are you "unable" to use it? What did you try and what went wrong? Please post any errors you got.

Comment: Hi ForceBru, windows parameter provides fixed windows of 2,3 or n previous entries. the next column should ideally calculate mean of first 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,....,n entries. So single value of windows is not helping me. Please do let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it using [cumulative sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to calculate sums of previous elements and deviding those sums by count of elements used in sum. Here is example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'C': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df['D'] = df['C'].cumsum() / range(1, df.shape[0] + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has an inbuilt 'expanding' method that does exactly what you are looking to do.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df['D']=df['C'].expanding(2).sum()/df['C'].expanding(2).count()
print(df)
```